# Apache HTTPD: allowed clients

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

When an Apache HTTPD is used as a load balancer, is it possible to configure it on a way that all the requests are rejected except those coming from a specific host?
What directive should be used?

Comment: By 'specific host' you mean 'specific IP address'?

Comment: Also, what is the Apache version?